# Is it possible to detect when all "static" dependencies were resolved?

Tags: node.js

```
// a.js
require('express');
require('./b');

// b.js
require('./c');
require('mocha');

// c.js
// I would like to detect here when all "static" dependencies were resolved (express, mocha, b)
```

- assuming no "dynamic" imports
- assuming no circular dependencies

Is there any global event when all static dependencies were resolved? Or any other way to fire such event (asynchronously)?

---

Edit:

It seems I can achieve this with following code:

```
process.nextTick(() => {
  console.log(Object.keys(require.cache));
});
```

Code above should be executed when all "static" requires were resolved/loaded. Of course if event loop will be busy (infinite loop for example) this code will never be executed. As far I tested it seems to work.

Comment: By "resolved", do you mean determining the filesystem path that corresponds to the module name?

Comment: By "resolved" I mean that file was loaded by node and code inside executed. I mean synchronous code. And all dependencies of that file were also resolved.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I ask because Node's `module` system has a loaded notion of `resolve` to mean what I asked above. It should be possible to achieve what you described in your question by using a functional loop (ie. `setInterval` or similar) to inspect the value of `require.cache`. After issuing a call to `require`, Node stores (**a lot**) of metadata pertaining to the loaded module(s). Something along the lines of `Object.keys(require.cache)` executed inside a functional loop ought to be a good starting point.

Comment: So, either the `require.cache` becomes populated with metadata (a condition you can detect out-of-band of your running program), or `require` throws an error because it failed to load the requested name/path.

Comment: The strategy I am proposing would also allow you to detect dynamic imports.

Comment: Thanks @antino - see my edit, I think this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such global error handler for such a scenario. But out of the box try this solution,

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
    if (error.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
        console.log('Module not found error');
        // MODULE IS NOT RESOLVED
    }
});
```

Subscribe this event before loading modules. Since node throws `Cannot find module` error if module is not resolved relevant section (inside the if statement) will execute.

---

EDIT

In nodejs modules may load anytime during the runtime, so it is not possible (or practical) to have a handler to be called when all modules are resolved.

Instead you can import your modules inside a try, catch block if it is possible.